# Bucket sort analysis (How many times do i check if bucket is empty or not)

Tags: sorting, bucket

How many buckets do I need to sort 10 elements? Lets say each record has a key how many times do i need to get the key composition. Lastly, How many times do I check if the bucket is empty or not?

I think the answer is 10 for each one of them, but I am confused.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am new to this topic, so as of now I have learned that the number of buckets will be equal to the number of elements in the array. Then for each element it will check wether the bucket is empty or not. Finally it will add the elements into the bucket. I am not fully sure if i am right though. Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

Bucket sort can have varying numbers of buckets depending on how you want to balance space and time complexity. If you use 10 or more buckets in this case and each key has its own bucket, your runtime for *n* elements and N buckets will be O(n+N). Otherwise, runtime will depend on the sorting algorithm used within each bucket since there may be buckets with multiple elements.

The algorithm assumes each element already has a key associated with it, so  if I am understanding what you are asking, you will need to "get the key composition" once for each element as you place them into buckets and also as you output the sorted list.

Finally, you will not necessarily need to check if the bucket is empty depending on how your algorithm handles the sorting of each individual bucket. Given an element *[k,e]* where *k* is the key and *e* is the element, it will be placed in bucket *k* whether or not that bucket is empty. Your algorithm may maintain a sorted list for each bucket, or it may sort all buckets before it outputs the final sorted list. This can affect the number of checks for emptiness. Lastly, when the algorithm outputs the sorted list, it will skip over the empty buckets, so this may require a check for emptiness each time.